# Why is my querySelectorAll not working even though I converted it to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom, foreach

## querySelectorAll is not working

Hey guys I have been trying to inject some data from my JavaScript file to my index html with DOM manipulation (querySelectorAll) but it is not working.

Note that I have also tried converting nodelist into an array for it to be displayed on html but to no avail, it still does not work. I've spent some time googling for a similar problem but I could not find one.

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card-row')
const newCard = Array.from(card)


const data = [{
    topic: 'Food',
    title: 'Wake Up and Smell the Coffee',
    price: '$0.90',
    color: green
  },
  {
    topic: 'Architecture',
    title: 'The Brand New NASA Office',
    price: '$0.19',
    color: black
  },
  {
    topic: 'Travel',
    title: 'Experience the Saharan Sands',
    price: '$2.29',
    color: brown
  },
  {
    topic: 'Interior',
    title: '9 Air-Cleaning Plants Your Home Needs',
    price: '$0.09',
    color: greenblue
  },
  {
    topic: 'Food',
    title: 'One Month Sugar Detox',
    price: '$0.99',
    color: pink
  },
  {
    topic: 'Photography',
    title: 'Shooting Minimal Instagram Photos',
    price: '$0.29',
    color: blue
  }
]
data.forEach(info => {
  card.innerHTML += `
      <span>${info.topic}</span>
      <h3>${info.title}</h3>
      <p>${info.price}</p>
    `
})
```

```css
.card-row {
  width: 300px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div style='margin: 40px 10px 40px'>
      <h1>Lifestyle.</h1>
      <p>The latest and best lifestyle articles selected<br/> by our editorial office.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='card-row'></div>
    <div class='card-row'></div>
    <div class='card-row'></div>
    <div class='card-row'></div>
    <div class='card-row'></div>
    <div class='card-row'></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically, I want my data variable to loop and inject the objects inside my cards. I have tried using only querySelector and of course it works for the first card but that is not what I want to achieve.

I could also give each card an id and manually put each data's object but it is not efficient and I'm trying to avoid long code.

#### I hope my explanation is clear enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your `data`array what is `green`?

Comment: querySelectorAll absolutely *is* working, it's your code that isn't.  Sorry if that seems harsh, but it's also the attitude you need to take if you're going to become a good programmer.

Comment: I get an error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: green is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the same amount amount of `.card-row` elements as you have entries in `data`, you can just pass the index as the second parameter in your `forEach`, and use that to select the correct `.card-row` element

```
data.forEach((info, i) => {
  card[i].innerHTML += `
      <span>${info.topic}</span>
      <h3>${info.title}</h3>
      <p>${info.price}</p>
    `
})
```

Also, there's two other issues:

1. In your example data, you're missing the `'` on your color values for them to be treated as Strings (Could just be something you forgot to include)
2. You've defined `newCard` but then use `card` for your forEach

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card-row')
const newCard = Array.from(card)

const data = [{
    topic: 'Food',
    title: 'Wake Up and Smell the Coffee',
    price: '$0.90',
    color: 'green'
  },
  {
    topic: 'Architecture',
    title: 'The Brand New NASA Office',
    price: '$0.19',
    color: 'black'
  },
  {
    topic: 'Travel',
    title: 'Experience the Saharan Sands',
    price: '$2.29',
    color: 'brown'
  },
  {
    topic: 'Interior',
    title: '9 Air-Cleaning Plants Your Home Needs',
    price: '$0.09',
    color: 'greenblue'
  },
  {
    topic: 'Food',
    title: 'One Month Sugar Detox',
    price: '$0.99',
    color: 'pink'
  },
  {
    topic: 'Photography',
    title: 'Shooting Minimal Instagram Photos',
    price: '$0.29',
    color: 'blue'
  }
];

data.forEach((info, i) => {
  card[i].innerHTML += `
      <span>${info.topic}</span>
      <h3>${info.title}</h3>
      <p>${info.price}</p>
    `
})
```

```css
.card-row {
  width: 300px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style='margin: 40px 10px 40px'>
    <h1>Lifestyle.</h1>
    <p>The latest and best lifestyle articles selected<br/> by our editorial office.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class='card-row'></div>
  <div class='card-row'></div>
  <div class='card-row'></div>
  <div class='card-row'></div>
  <div class='card-row'></div>
  <div class='card-row'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I really appreciate it. When I run the code snippet it works, but when I put the solution on vsc, it gives me the error of "TypeError: card[i] is undefined" Any clue why it triggers that?

Comment: I'm not sure - probably check that `card` contains the values you expect, and that like I say you've got the correct amount of Elements . Hard to say without seeing the code

Answer (score 0):

Look your data is iterable(something that can be mapped by loop)  and your card's array is also an iterable one because you have selected it with querySelectorAll. it returns a iterable node list. So you can not use card.innerHtml directly. Look there is a suggestion for it. Don't make empty  .card-row element in Html. Rather generate html in javascript when you iterating over your data array. You can generate html in Javascript with.  .createElement(). I think that is much flexible and now you have more control in your code. 
The code should look  something like that:

```
data.forEach((info) => {
   card = document.createElement('div').classList().add('card-row').innerHTML = `
  <span>${info.topic}</span>
  <h3>${info.title}</h3>
  <p>${info.price}</p>
`; document.querySeletor('.container').append(card);});
```

I think that is much clearer. (you don't need to select the card at the top)